# How/ could you rewrite this as Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing this and was just wondering as I'm new to all of this if Linq could be used to rewrite this?

```
private void checkacrobat()
{
    Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach(Process pr in prs)
    {
         if(pr.ProcessName == "****ProcessName")
              pr.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p=>p.ProcessName==whatever))
    process.Kill();
```

Remember, use *statements* for *actions* like killing a process. Use LINQ for *queries*, that read values without changing them.

But your code is perfectly readable as it is. I wouldn't change it without a good reason.

Comment: I wish I could accept all the answers! This is just me trying to get my head around a real world (to me) example. I'm dipping my toe in the water that is Linq! Thanks Eric I liked the simplicity of your answer. Thanks Ani for the "Purpose-built method" I will use this in my code. and to all of the other answers I think I have learnt a lot from them all.

Answer (score 5):

**In method syntax:**

```
var processesToBeKilled = Process.GetProcesses()
                                 .Where(pr => pr.ProcessName == "****ProcessName");

foreach(var process in processesToBeKilled)
   process.Kill();
```

**In query syntax:**

```
var processesToBeKilled = from pr in Process.GetProcesses()
                          where pr.ProcessName == "****ProcessName"
                          select pr;

foreach(var process in processesToBeKilled)
   process.Kill();
```

**Purpose-built method:**

There's really no need for LINQ here; there's already the handy  [**`Process.GetProcessesByName`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) method:

```
var processesToBeKilled = Process.GetProcessesByName("****ProcessName");

foreach(var process in processesToBeKilled)
   process.Kill();
```

Comment: +1 for `Process.GetProcessesByName`, which is probably the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that LINQ is for querying, projecting and aggregating. You are doing something with a side effect here and LINQ isn't appropriate for that. So, I separate the query part away from the side effecty part.

```
private void KillProcessesWithName(string processName) {
    var processesToKill = Process.GetProcesses()
                                 .Where(p => p.ProcessName == processName);
    foreach(var process in processesToKill) {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

It is arguable whether or not the LINQified version is better and I would keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable doesn't have a ForEach extension method so you can't fully rewrite it as LINQ (unless you use your own ForEach extension)

```
Process[] processes in Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process pr in processes.Where(p => p.ProcessName == "****ProcessName"))
{
pr.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Rewriting using a `ForEach` extension to obtain a side effect would be evil.

Answer (score 1):

```
var processes = from process in Process.GetProceeses()
where process.ProcessName == "****ProcessName"
select process;

foreach(var p in processes){
    p.Kill()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the List has an ForEach-extension you could use.

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p=>p.ProcessName==whatever).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill);
```